# MongoDB: Populate reference in $group when aggregating?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection that I need to group by year. My aggregation pipeline is as such:

```js
const WorkHistoryByYear = await this.workHistroyModel.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$year',
      history: {
        $push: '$$ROOT'
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Which works as expected, returning:

```json
[{
  "_id": 2003,
  "history": [
    {
      "_id": "600331b3d84ac418877a0e5a",
      "tasksPerformed": [
        "5fffb180a477c4f78ad67331",
        "5fffb18aa477c4f78ad67332"
      ],
      "year": 2003
    },
    {
      "_id": "600331dcd84ac418877a0e5c",
      "tasksPerformed": [
        "5fffb180a477c4f78ad67331"
      ],
      "year": 2003
    }
  ]
}]
```

but I'd like to populate a field if possible.

The WorkHistory schema has a field, `tasksPerformed` which is an array of ObjectId references. Here is the `Task` schema:

```js
export const TaskSchema = new Schema({
  active: {
    type: Schema.Types.Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
  title: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: true,
  },
  order: {
    type: Schema.Types.Number,
    index: true,
  }
});
```

Is it possible to populate the referenced models within the aggregation? [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) seems to be what I need, but I have yet to get that to work when following the documentation.

I don't do a lot of database work, so I'm having some difficulty finding the right operator(s) to use, and I've seen similar questions, but not a definitive answer.

Edit:

After adding the code from @varman's answer, my return is now:

```json
{
  "_id": 2003,
  "history": {
    "_id": "600331b3d84ac418877a0e5a",
    "tasksPerformed": [
      "5fffb180a477c4f78ad67331",
      "5fffb18aa477c4f78ad67332"
    ],
    "year": 2003,
    "history": {
      "tasksPerformed": []
    }
  }
}
```

I converted the ObjectId references to strings in an effort to help the matching, but I'm still coming up short.

Comment: Can you post some sample data

Comment: @varman I've added a condensed example of the aggregated data

Comment: Population inside the model is possible and what you said about `$lookup` is also correct. Can we have other collection that you need to join?

Comment: @varman I've added the schema for the related "Task" model

Comment: Does `TaskSchema ` have reference of workhistory?

Comment: It does not. WorkHistory contains the reference to one or more tasks.

Comment: Sorry my fault, `TaskSchema` has _id filed right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for the example. I didn't even know Mongo Playground existed. I see the example works, but my aggregate is now returning an empty array. The "TaskSchema" is stored in the DB as the "tasks" collection, so I changed the lookup.from to reflect that. However, I'm not sure why the return is empty.

Comment: I don't want to disturb your effort, so I used your result. But `$unwind` is expensive. Better to do the lookup at the beginning without unwind. This might be the efficient way. I hope you schema is also same like here https://mongoplayground.net/p/4lIu9H0R71W

Comment: Check your spellings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the lookup to join both collections

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array. (Array to Objects)
- `$lookup` to join collections
- `$group` to reconstruct the deconstructed array again

The script for the above result is

```
db.workHistory.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$history"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "taskSchema",
      "localField": "history.tasksPerformed",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "history.tasksPerformed"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "history": {
        "$push": "$history"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_vh6sD95o6l)**

But before grouping, you have collection look like this

```
db={
  "workHistory": [
    {
      "_id": 2003,
      "history": [
        {
          "_id": "600331b3d84ac418877a0e5a",
          "tasksPerformed": [
            "5fffb180a477c4f78ad67331",
            "5fffb18aa477c4f78ad67332"
          ],
          "year": 2003
        },
        {
          "_id": "600331dcd84ac418877a0e5c",
          "tasksPerformed": [
            "5fffb180a477c4f78ad67331"
          ],
          "year": 2003
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "taskSchema": [
    {
      "_id": "5fffb180a477c4f78ad67331",
      "active": true,
      "title": "first"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fffb18aa477c4f78ad67332",
      "active": true,
      "title": "second"
    }
  ]
}
```

Since `$unwind` is expensive, we could have done aggregation

```
db.workHistory.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "taskSchema",
      "localField": "tasksPerformed",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "tasksPerformed"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$year",
      history: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4lIu9H0R71W)

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure what's up with my collections, but my aggregate is returning: `{
    "_id": 2003,
    "history": {
      "_id": "600331b3d84ac418877a0e5a",
      "tasksPerformed": [
        "5fffb180a477c4f78ad67331",
        "5fffb18aa477c4f78ad67332"
      ],
      "year": 2003,
      "history": {
        "tasksPerformed": []
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: I converted the ObjectID references to strings, but that also didn't help.

Comment: I have updated the answer, does the second answer help you? If nit, can you give me a mongoplayground like that shows your sample data of both collections?

Comment: The "taskSchema" is stored as the collection "tasks". I updated the Mongo playground example to match that name, and it works there, it just doesn't work in my code within NestJS

Comment: have you changed the name inside the lookup also?

Comment: Yes. I'm going to have to pick this up tomorrow as it's 12:09 AM in my part of the world :) Thank you very much for the help, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Let me know the result :D . You are welcome

Comment: I didn't see that you had changed the `localField` and `as` properties to remove `history.`. I removed those and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

you could also do it [without an unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#use-lookup-with-an-array):

```
db.WorkHistory.aggregate(
[
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Tasks",
            localField: "tasksPerformed",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "tasksPerformed"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$year",
            history: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    }
])
```